# JavaScript: TextArea onload

Tags: javascript, html, input, load, textarea

I have two elements as `textarea`,`textarea1` loads DATA from sql server and I want when `textarea1`  finishs loading to transfer the value to textarea2 on JavaScript.

```
<script>
            function keypressed(e){
                if(e.keyCode === 13){
                send_command();
                }
                return false;
            }
            var txtarea = document.getElementById('textarea2');
            function send_command(e) {
                $('#textarea1').load("../test/tester?", {'text': $('#input1').val()});        (textarea1 loads data from sql server)
                $('#input1').val('');
                return false;   
            }
            $(function() {
                $("#input1").focus();
                texto.innerHTML += ">> " + $('#input1').val()+"\n" + $('#textarea1').val(); 
            }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function as parameter to load function and it will get executed if it is completed:

```
$('#textarea1').load("TEST", function() {
  $('#textarea').load("TEST");
});
```

For more info look [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Update:

If you just want to set text of the textarea you can use `val` and then call change which triggers the change event of first textarea:

```
$("textarea#textarea1").val('TEST').change();
```

Then bind the change event of the same textarea to a function, get the value and set it to the second one:

```
$('textarea#textarea1').change(function() {
  $('#textarea').val($("textarea#textarea1").val());
});
```

I created a plunker for you [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7fhrovCrunAR47OGgZ6s?p=preview).

UPDATE

Follow this:

```
$(function() {
     $('#textarea1').change(function() {
          $("#input1").val( $("#input1").val() + '\n' +  $('#textarea1').val());
     });

})();
```

Also note the self executing at the end of that function if you intend to use an `IIFE`.

Comment: textarea2 looses the previous values on load event, but I want the textarea2 to keep its values and to add textare1's value.

Comment: Can you just put your code here please so, it can be understand that how you make call...

Comment: That is what I want, I will test it with my code today.

Comment: Sorry but can you update your post instead of pasting the code in comments?

Comment: It didnt work for me but here is my code :
I want as soon as textarea finish loading the data from sql server to pass its value to textarea2, I tried on focus, load but no success, but still open to your suggesions.

Comment: I think you didn't follow the answer completely, instead of hooking to focus just hook into change event